# ¿Cuándo usar diccionarios y cuando usar tuplas en Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Cuando tengo que pasar parámetros a una función normalmente en Objective-C lo hago mediante un diccionario. En Swift esto se puede hacer también con tuplas.

¿Para trabajar con Swift qué es mas aconsejable, usar diccionarios o tuplas? ¿Cuáles son los pros y contras entre usar uno u otro sistema?

Comment: Resumido:
Un diccionario es clave-valor, y se pasan por referencia.
Una dupla puede ser clave-valor ó indice-valor(tupla.0) y se pasan por valor.

Answer (score 2):

una tupla es una pareja de 2 variables, da lo mismo de lo que sea cada una y un diccionario es un conjunto de clave-valor. Por ejemplo si quieres tener país y capital y lo tienes en una tupla tendrás un primer elemento de la tupla que sera el país y un segundo que sera la capital. Tendrías algo como esto:

```
var tupla1: (String, String) = ("España", "Madrid")
```

En un diccionario tendrás una clave que sera el país y un valor que sera la capital. Si quieres añadir otro país, en la tupla ya no te cabe, tenderas que crear otra tupla y en el diccionario solo añades otro clave valor,

```
var tupla2: (String, String) = ("Francia", "Paris")
```

Si haces un array de tuplas, podría simular un diccionario, pero cuando quisieras saber la capital de Francia, con el diccionario accederías muy fácil con Diccionario["Francia"]. Con la tupla no existe esta opción, deberías ir buscando en ese array de tuplas hasta que encuentras una que tenga como primer elemento "Francia", tendrías algo como esto:

```
var array: [(String, String)] = [("España", "Madrid"), ("Francia", "Paris")]
```

Espero que te haya servido

Comment: En tuplas puedes poner mas de 2 variables aquí un ejemplo:
 var film: (pelicula: String, year:Double, rank:Float)  = ("Interstellar", 2014, 10.0) y también puedes devolver  varios valores de una función con una tupla. Por eso quería saber que es mas aconsejable a la hora de trabajar tuplas o diccionarios ?

Comment: Depende de para que, si luego vas a usar la funcionalidad de un diccionario para acceder rápidamente a un valor, las duplas no te dan esa opción

Answer (score 1):

Las tuplas y los diccionarios son estructuras de datos distintas, cada una con sus características. Si bien en tu caso de "pasar parámetros a una función" puede hacerse con cualquiera de las dos, no son intercambiables.

De hecho, una tupla podría ser más parecido a un `struct` anónimo (por así decirlo) que a un diccionario.

Con respecto a tu caso de uso (pasar parámetros a un función):

- Lo mejor es pasar los valores de a uno, cada uno con su tipo de datos. Agregarlos en una tupla o en un diccionario es innecesario, agrega complejidad al código y afecta el rendimiento en ejecución.
- Dicho esto, si de todas formas no los quieres pasar de a uno, entonces tendría en cuenta que:

  - si son pocos parámetros y siempre están presentes todos, usaría una tupla
  - si son muchos y son todos opcionales, y además la mayoría de las veces voy a pasarle un conjunto reducido de parámetros, entonces usaría un diccionario.

Comment: En mi caso suelo usar Diccionarios en Objective-C al pasar valores a una función porque estos valores con llave suelen variar. Por eso quería saber en Swift  si con tuplas se suele hacer lo mismo o cual es el motivo de trabajar con tuplas ?

Comment: No, en ese caso deberías seguir usando diccionarios. Las tuplas en general se usan para devolver más de un valor en una función. Por ejemplo, una función que devolviera el resultado de una conexión HTTP podría devolver una tupla con el `status` y la descripción del mismo.